# string is partially parsed when symbol "&" is present

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing

If I have a string like "Fuel & Additives" when my XML parser goes through it ignores anything **BEFORE** the "**&**" symbol, why?

```
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"GLDesc"]) 
{
   currentParsedObjectContainer.GLDesc = currentNodeContent;
       NSLog(@"%@",currentParsedObjectContainer.GLDesc);
}
```

Comment: In xml, `&` has to be escaped to `&amp;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The ampersand character (&) and the
>   left angle bracket (<) may appear in
>   their literal form only when used as
>   markup delimiters, or within a
>   comment, a processing instruction, or
>   a CDATA section. If they are needed
>   elsewhere, they must be escaped using
>   either numeric character references or
>   the strings "&" and "<"
>   respectively.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#syntax

As the above snippet states, you'll need to escape & to the string `&amp;` before passing it to the XML parser.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to say it has something to do with character codes (for example &lt).  I'm not really familiar with xml though, so I'm not sure.  Try &amp?